# How to simulation propeller using openfoam8

Tags: openfoam

first, I'm sorry. I can't speak English well.
I'm talking using google translate.

I'm not used to using openfoam.

I want to simulation propeller using openfoam8, but openfoam8 haven't pimpleDyMFoam.

Please teach me how to simulation propeller using openfoam8.

thanks.

Comment: You have to try first and ask some issues in your code.

Comment: thank you for answering my questions. I tried simulation using pimpleFoam. `Source tutorial run functions
. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/tools/RunFunctions

# Copy propeller surfaces from resources directory
cp $FOAM_TUTORIALS/resources/geometry/propeller*.obj.gz constant/triSurface/

# Meshing
runApplication blockMesh
runApplication surfaceFeatures
runApplication snappyHexMesh -overwrite

# Create the inlet/outlet and AMI patches
runApplication createBaffles -overwrite
runApplication mergeOrSplitBaffles -split -overwrite

# Renumbering
runApplication renumberMesh -noFields -overwrite`

Comment: I don't know what to do after this. What should i do？

Comment: @sam: Try to run "Propeller" case  from OpenFOAM tutorials. Just run the script `./Allrun`

Comment: @s.ouchene Thank you! I solved this question.